# Como funciona a sobrecarga de operador?

Tags: python, classes, operadores, sobrecarga

Como funciona este código?

```
class MyClass:
   def __init__(self, *args):
      self.Input = args

   def __add__(self, Other):
      Output = MyClass()
      Output.Input = self.Input + Other.Input
      return Output

   def __str__(self):
      Output = ""
      for Item in self.Input:
         Output += Item
         Output += " "
      return Output

Value1 = MyClass("Red", "Green", "Blue")
Value2 = MyClass("Yellow", "Purple", "Cyan")
Value3 = Value1 + Value2

print("{0} + {1} = {2}"
      .format(Value1, Value2, Value3))
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 4):

Não tem muito segredo, o operador usado em uma expressão é na verdade um açúcar sintático, portanto ele não é bem o que você está vendo. Na verdade a linha

```
Value3 = Value1 + Value2
```

Executará algo como

```
Value3 = Value1.__add__(Value2)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Operator/Overload.py).

Então apenas é chamado o método descrito na classe.

Note que o primeiro operando determinará qual classe será utilizada para chamar o método, já que esse método pode estar presente em diversas classes. No caso `Value1` é do tipo `MyClass` portanto é o método `__add__()` dentro de `MyClass` que será chamado, mas isso nem é sobre o operador, vale para qualquer método.

Ele é um pouco diferente porque o operator tem características especiais na linguagem, principalmente pode ser notada precedência entre operadores quando há vários operandos e precisa decidir qual operador é executado primeiro, se fosse um método normal não haverá precedência, só associação.

Comment: Sim, entendi essa parte, obrigado. Mas por exemplo, pode me explicar como funciona as variáveis como "Output.Input" ou "Other.Input", e por que elas são atreladas assim? Por exemplo, no metodo __add__, ele tem um argumento 'Other', mas logo em seguinda, quando ele define 'Output.Input', 'Other' é anexado com um ponto '.' a palavra 'Input', isso que eu não entendi, essa anexagem a partir de um ponto, visto que 'Other' é um argumento ja existente e que recebe os valores de "Value 2" (ao final do código)

Comment: Isso não é a sobrecarga, isso é um algoritmo específico, é outra pergunta. De qualquer forma, parece que está fazendo mais sofisticadas do que entende. Para dar um exemplo, você fez uma pergunta sobre como pintar uma casa, quando ainda não sabe como assentar um tijolo, está aprendendo de forma de forma equivocada e vai criando confusão. Procure uma forma mais estruturada de aprender pegando cada conceito de cada vez em uma ordem estabelecida por alguém que sabe o que é mais importante primeiro. Esse conceito é anterior à sobrecarga. Quando pergunta algo avançado presume-se que conhece o básico

Comment: Valeu, consegui entender agr.